# Implementing optimistic concurrency on DbUpdateConcurrencyExpcetion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, concurrency, exception

I'm working on an application that needs to handle `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, and was browsing the web for suggestions on implementation. I found a specific implementation in multiple resources, e.g. [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3085390/application-development/how-to-handle-concurrency-conflicts-in-entity-framework.html) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183935/%2FArticles%2F1183935%2FConcurrency-Handling-In-Entity-Framework-Databas) (look near bottom in both resources)

Their implementation is the following:

```
try
{
    //...
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
    entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues()); //<----
}
```

**My question/what I would like to understand:**

Pay attention to the second line of the `catch` clause. How does it solve the exception, that I set the database values (current values) to overwrite the original values?

Notice that I am familiar with concurrency in general, and I am familiar with the terms current-, database-, and original values. I am not interested in an explanation of what it means, but interested in **WHY** this is a good way to resolve concurrency issues, and **why it makes sense** to overwrite the original values.

Thank you

Comment: Why would it be bad? What are your  concerns with that approach? It just updates the original values, the changes you performed are still being tracked and will be applied when you repeat the option. Since the concurrency token is changed its will correctly update (unless another process changed it in the meantime)

Comment: @Tseng I didn't mention anywhere, that "it would be bad". In the end of my post, I elaborated a bit: "... but [I am] interested in WHY this is a good way to resolve concurrency issues, and why it makes sense to overwrite the original values." You say it works fine - thats great. I am interested in understanding why it is a good way to resolve the exception, specifically why overwriting original values is a good approach to handle concurrency issues.

Comment: _and why overwriting original values is a good approach to handle concurrency issues._ happens because of the changed concurrency token. Overriding it, puts the new token from the database into the entity tracker. Alternative would be do another round trip, load the data from the DB again, apply the changes and attempt to save it again

Comment: @Tseng Thank you